# getDbTable()->select()->where issue (Zend Framework 1.x)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I've currently got a query I'm preparing in Zend 1.x.
The select query is formed within a class as you'd expect:

I'm setting up the query as follows:

```
    // prepare query
    $this->getDbTable()->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('mdt' => 'meta_data_type'))
        ->where('id = :id')
        ->bind(
            array(
                ':id' => $id
            )
        );
    // report SQL for debugging
    echo $this->getDbTable()->select()->__toString();
```

As you can see, this isn't exactly the hardest query. However: the returned SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT `meta_data_type`.* FROM `meta_data_type`
```

Can anyone give me any gotchas on how to debug this? It seems correct to me. 
I've tried to follow the examples online, but given our system approach (sat inside a Mapper pattern, with non-standard table namings amongst other things) this isn't too much help.

FYI : The actual data it returns matches what you'd expect from a "get row" operation on a "complete data set".. as in: the first row is well formed. It's just not constrained by the where clause (as you'd expect with it missing from SQL!).

FYI 2 : The bind/where isn't the issue. If I change the whole ending to:

```
->where('id = 2');
```

It still does not show this inside the clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks okay, although this isn't the syntax I used to use with ZF1. However, by calling `$this->getDbTable()->select()` a second time for the echo, you are outputting a fresh new query without any of your params.

Simplest fix would be to assign it to a variable instead:

```
// prepare query
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select()
               ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
               ->from(array('mdt' => 'meta_data_type'))
               ->where('id = :id')
               ->bind(
                    array(
                        ':id' => $id
                    )
                );

// report SQL for debugging
echo $select;
```

Comment: So, thanks to Tim Fountain. This seems to be exactly the problem: 
The original query is being completely overwritten by a default. Good spot! +1 internet to you.
(I mentioned that this was a slight simplification of my code and this fix applies there as well)